# Should I use mutually exclusive options on my command line tool?

Tags: command-line, utilities, options

Writing a CLI tool, I'm facing a conundrum.

The tool is supposed to detect faces in images and blur them automatically. However, sometimes only one of those things should be done to allow marking additional faces manually with an external tool. So there are three behaviours I want to support:

1. Detect faces and blur them in one go
2. Only detect faces
3. Only blur faces

My idea of solving this were two mutually exclusive options, something like `--only-detect` and `--only-blur`.

However, a coworker suggested that it might make more sense to have `--detect` and `--blur`, so that using both options would lead to the same behaviour as using none, but I find this to be less intuitive.

My question now is: *Are there any conventions I can follow to make this decision?* I found the [POSIX Utility Conventions](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html), and they do mention mutually exclusive groups, but nothing that is helpful here.

Comment: `--only-foo` is not something I think I've ever encountered in a tool; there's a few that do `--no-foo`, and `--no-blur --no-detect` wouldn't be mutually exclusive, nor would ` ` be the same as `--blur --detect`.

Comment: Why not write two programs?

Comment: @UlrichSchwarz That is very useful information! In that case, what would no options do? Just nothing? Or print the help text? Or did you mean to say no options would not be the same as `--no-blur --no-detect`?

Comment: @CharlesDiploma because most of the time, they are executed together. Executing them separately is a special use-case that's only useful in some specific cases.

Comment: @iFreilicht if the most common action is to do both, then you should make that the default. After that, you could have `--action=blur`, `--action=detect` and `--action=both` and state that the default is `--action=both`. Or just abbreviate those to `--blur`, `--detect` and `--both`, so that no-one needs to complain about having to type too much... (of course, if you ever add any functions, the "both" option starts to seem odd.) But whatever you do, document the options and the default. Other than that, I think it's just up to you as the author.

Comment: @iFreilicht: sorry, the second part switched over to your suggestion. No options would do your common case of doing both, and `--no-blur --no-detect` could either complain or just copy the file, whichever makes more sense to you.

Comment: I'd go with your coworker's suggestion.

Comment: @dr01 yes, after reading the answers and other comments, this does seem like the better solution.

Answer (score 8):

POSIX just says (regarding mutually exclusive command line options in POSIX utilities):

> The use of conflicting mutually-exclusive arguments produces undefined results, unless a utility description specifies otherwise.

---

Some command line tools have conflicting command line options (such as both a `--silent` option and a `--verbose` option).  In the case that both options are used when invoking the tool, if allowed, the last parsed option (the one last on the line) usually wins.

The last one of `--blur` and `--detect` would be used.  The documentation would specify what options were exclusive.

Compare `ls -l -C` with `ls -C -l`, for example.

---

Other tools simply disallow conflicting command line options, giving the user a diagnostic message on the standard error stream and exiting with a non-zero exit code when such a situation occurs.

Your code would error out if both `--blur` and `--detect` were used.

This is done in e.g. `cut` which has conflicting flags `-b`, `-c` and `-f`.

---

Some tools may provide a different effect depending on what name it is invoked as.  So, you could have two names (hard links) for your tool, one called `detectface` and another called `blurface`.  These would be the exact same binary but the program would determine what name it was invoked as to figure out what operation to perform.

This is common on system where some shell masquerades as both `/bin/sh` (a POSIX shell) and as itself (e.g. `bash` on Linux, or `ksh` on OpenBSD) and that switches to "POSIX `sh` mode" when invoked as `sh`, or you might have a compiler that compiles both C and C++ code and switches mode depending on whether it's invoked as `cc` or `c++`, etc. (both `gcc` and `clang` does this).

Comment: Very interesting info about the symlink-dependant behaviour. I think your answer really shows that mutually exclusive options are to be avoided when possible.

Answer (score 3):

I'd ask myself what the user will want the program to do in most cases and make exactly that the default behaviour. This default behaviour should be triggered automatically when no option is specified. On the other hand *if* there is an option specified, *nothing* should be done by the command unless specified with an option.

---

Here's a counterexample of what I consider **painfully poor** programming:

```
avconv -i file.avi
```

outputs some information about your video file, `-i` sets the input file and as there's no output specified `avconv` takes it you just want the info.

```
avconv file.avi
```

overwrites your precious video without any warning or doing a backup, because `avconv` willfully takes the argument as the output file and writes to it *no matter what*, even if there's nothing to write.

I think you get the point.

---

Here's what I'd call intuitive. If the default behaviour is

- both detect and blur:

  - `command` and
    `command --detect --blur` does detect and blur
  - `command --detect` does only detect
  - `command --blur` does only blur
- just one, e.g. for detect:

  - `command` and
    `command --detect` does only detect
  - `command --blur` does only blur
  - `command --detect --blur` does detect and blur, if you feel like this is useful there's also 
    `command --detectblur` as a shorthand for this

I'd also define the short options `-d` and `-b` so that users can call `command -bd` to set both options no matter what the default behaviour is.

Comment: Yes, the default is to do both. Thanks for providing the counterexample!